# What is the time complexity of String initialization with a Sequence?

Tags: swift, string, time-complexity

**What have I done so far?**

1. I looked at the public [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(_:)-8og6g) for the initializer.
2. I looked at the [open source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/String.swift), see code below.

**Detail**

After looking at the method definition, I think we can further clarify the question by saying that the `Sequence`/`Array` will be stored in contiguous bytes and `UTF8` will be used.

---

```
  /// Creates a string from the given Unicode code units in the specified
  /// encoding.
  ///
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - codeUnits: A collection of code units encoded in the encoding
  ///     specified in `sourceEncoding`.
  ///   - sourceEncoding: The encoding in which `codeUnits` should be
  ///     interpreted.
  @inlinable
  @inline(__always) // Eliminate dynamic type check when possible
  public init<C: Collection, Encoding: Unicode.Encoding>(
    decoding codeUnits: C, as sourceEncoding: Encoding.Type
  ) where C.Iterator.Element == Encoding.CodeUnit {
    guard _fastPath(sourceEncoding == UTF8.self) else {
      self = String._fromCodeUnits(
        codeUnits, encoding: sourceEncoding, repair: true)!.0
      return
    }

    // Fast path for user-defined Collections and typed contiguous collections.
    //
    // Note: this comes first, as the optimizer nearly always has insight into
    // wCSIA, but cannot prove that a type does not have conformance to
    // _HasContiguousBytes.
    if let str = codeUnits.withContiguousStorageIfAvailable({
      (buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer<C.Element>) -> String in
      Builtin.onFastPath() // encourage SIL Optimizer to inline this closure :-(
      let rawBufPtr = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(buffer)
      return String._fromUTF8Repairing(
        UnsafeBufferPointer(
          start: rawBufPtr.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self),
          count: rawBufPtr.count)).0
    }) {
      self = str
      return
    }

    // Fast path for untyped raw storage and known stdlib types
    if let contigBytes = codeUnits as? _HasContiguousBytes,
      contigBytes._providesContiguousBytesNoCopy
    {
      self = contigBytes.withUnsafeBytes { rawBufPtr in
        Builtin.onFastPath() // encourage SIL Optimizer to inline this closure
        return String._fromUTF8Repairing(
          UnsafeBufferPointer(
            start: rawBufPtr.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self),
            count: rawBufPtr.count)).0
      }
      return
    }

    self = String._fromNonContiguousUnsafeBitcastUTF8Repairing(codeUnits).0
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a *formal* analysis of time complexity, but hopefully specific enough to satisfy your needs: the time complexity of creating a string from a collection of code units is **O(n)** (where `n` is the length of the input collection in code units).

`String` initialization from a `Collection` of code units has three initialization paths:

1. [`String._fromCodeUnits(_:encoding:repair:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/113bfc77fbcd47362ce57424ee79549f7ab8cefc/stdlib/public/core/StringCreate.swift#L187) for non-UTF-8 input
2. [`String._fromUTF8Repairing(_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/113bfc77fbcd47362ce57424ee79549f7ab8cefc/stdlib/public/core/StringCreate.swift#L92C4-L92C4) for contiguous UTF-8 input (e.g., an existing string or an `Array` of UTF-8 code units)
3. [`String._fromNonContiguousUnsafeBitcastUTF8Repairing(_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/113bfc77fbcd47362ce57424ee79549f7ab8cefc/stdlib/public/core/String.swift#L431), which converts the input collection into an `Array`, then calls `String._fromUTF8Repairing(_:)` (2) on the resulting array

   - This copy is itself **O(n)**, as each code unit in the input collection is copied into the array (in constant-time per code unit)

So we have two cases to look at:

1. `String._fromCodeUnits(_:encoding:repair:)` itself has two main paths:

   - If the input is non-ASCII, each code unit is iterated and [transcoded](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/113bfc77fbcd47362ce57424ee79549f7ab8cefc/stdlib/public/core/Unicode.swift#L552) into UTF-8; transcoding from the possible input encodings is a constant-time operation (all of the supported encodings have a fixed upper bound on the length of the code unit in bytes, so there's a constant, fixed bound on the complexity of the operation) so the overall operation here is **O(n)** for construction
   - If the input is ASCII, each code unit is iterated and validated to be ASCII, then copied as-is (since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8); because each code unit is copied in constant time, the overall operation here is **O(n)**
2. `String._fromUTF8Repairing(_:)` [validates](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/113bfc77fbcd47362ce57424ee79549f7ab8cefc/stdlib/public/core/StringUTF8Validation.swift#L34) all of the code units in the input collection to ensure they're all valid UTF-8

   - If all are valid, the entire collection is [copied as-is](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/113bfc77fbcd47362ce57424ee79549f7ab8cefc/stdlib/public/core/StringCreate.swift#L137) (each code unit in constant time), and thus **O(n)**
   - If any code units are invalid, the string is [repaired](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/113bfc77fbcd47362ce57424ee79549f7ab8cefc/stdlib/public/core/StringUTF8Validation.swift#L156) by copying ranges of valid UTF-8 code units, and replacing ranges of invalid UTF-8 code units with the Unicode replacement character. Each code unit only needs to be accessed a single time, to be copied over if valid, or skipped over if invalid, which is done in constant time, which leaves the operation at **O(n)**

So:

1. ASCII input: **O(n)** (validation) + **O(n)** (copy) = **O(n)**
2. Non-ASCII, non-UTF-8 input: **O(n)** (transcoding + copying)
3. Contiguous UTF-8 input: **O(n)** (validation) + **O(n)** (repairing/copying) = **O(n)**
4. Non-contiguous UTF-8 input: **O(n)** (copying into an array) + **O(n)** (contiguous op (3)) = **O(n)**

---

Or, perhaps more intuitively:

- When you copy a string, you need to access each code unit one at a time to copy it
- Copying a single code unit is a constant-time operation (since a code unit has a fixed upper bound on its length in bytes)

  - If you choose to replace a code unit with a different one, you can make the decision in constant time (and copying *that* character is only constant time)

**O(n [length] * 1 [copy or replace]) = O(n)**